Match ISC DHCPv6 host fixed address by DUID+IAID?
My DHCPv6 client is using DUID-EN (Type 2, vendor ID 0x1234, unique ID 0x01) to send a DUID unique to the device, and has 2 network interfaces, each with their own MAC address (so for example eth0 has IAID 23:00:01, eth1 has IAID 23:00:01).
I'm using ISC DHCP server 4.4.
In the host block, I can use
host myHost {
    host-identifier option dhcp6.client-id 00:02:00:00:12:34:01;
    fixed-address 2001:192:168:0::1;
}

to match the DUID and assign a fixed IPv6 address, but is there a way to also match the IAID that is sent in the IA_NA portion of the Solicit, so that the interface gets the right address?
In DHCPv4 I can match option dhcp-client-identifier, which contains both IAID and DUID, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same for DHCPv6, as the client-id only contains the DUID.
in DHCPv4 I would use
host myHost_ETH0 {
    dhcp-client-identifier ff:23:00:01:00:02:00:00:12:34:01;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.1;
}
host myHost_ETH1 {
    dhcp-client-identifier ff:23:00:02:00:02:00:00:12:34:01;
    fixed-address 10.10.0.2;
}

